# Vertical justify doesn't work

Tags: css

I know this has been asked a thousand times but I find no simple solution there:

I do have that code a couple of times

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="image_1.png">
        <span>Name 1</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

and I want to justify the span and the img-element vertically. Therefore I did

```
li span, li img{
    display:block;
    margin:auto 10px;
}

li img{
    width:20%;
    height:auto
}
```

but there is no effect at all. What do I do wrong there?
What else could I do?

Comment: have you tried `vertical-align`?

Comment: yeah. All options on both elements :(

Comment: maybe try adding an absolute height (so using px) and using vertical align :)

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with flexbox: Is this what you're looking for

```css
li span, li img{
    display:block;
    margin:0 10px;
}

li img{
}

a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        <span>Name 1</span>
    </a>
</li>
```